# Is there a race condition in the golang implementation of mutex the m.state is read without atomic function

Tags: go, conditional-statements, mutex

In golang if two goroutines read and write a variable without mutex and atomic, that may bring data race condition.

Use command `go run --race xxx.go` will detect the race point.

While the implementation of Mutex in src/sync/mutex.go use the following code

```
       func (m *Mutex) Lock() {
   // Fast path: grab unlocked mutex.
   if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&m.state, 0, mutexLocked) {
       if race.Enabled {
           race.Acquire(unsafe.Pointer(m))
       }
       return
   }

   var waitStartTime int64
   starving := false
   awoke := false
   iter := 0
   old := m.state     // This line confuse me !!!
       ......
```

The code `old := m.state` confuse me, because m.state is read and write by different goroutine.

The following function Test obvious has race condition problem. But if i put it in mutex.go, no race conditon will detect.

```
# mutex.go
func Test(){
    a := int32(1)
        go func(){
                atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&a, 1, 4)
        }()
        _ = a
}
```

If put it in other package like src/os/exec.go, the conditon race problem will detect.

```
package main

import(
    "sync"
    "os"
)
func main(){
    sync.Test()        // race condition will not detect
    os.Test()          // race condition will detect
}
```

Comment: You should ask such questions on golang-nuts or golang-dev, not SO.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the golang source always changes so let's make sure we are looking at the same thing. Take release 1.12 at

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.12/src/sync/mutex.go

as you said the Lock function begins

```
func (m *Mutex) Lock() {
    // fast path where it will set the high order bit and return if not locked
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&m.state, 0, mutexLocked) {
        return
    }
    //reads value to decide on the lower order bits
    for {
        //if statements involving CompareAndSwaps on the lower order bits
    }
}
```

What is this CompareAndSwap doing? it looks atomically in that int32 and if it is 0 it swaps it to mutexLocked (which is 1 defined as a const above) and returns true that it swapped it. 
Then it promptly returns. That is its fast path. The goroutine acquired the lock and now it is running can start running it's protected path.

If it is 1 (mutexLocked) already, it doesn't swap it and returns false (it didn't swap it).

Then it reads the state and enters a loop that it does atomic compare and swaps to determine how it should behave.

What are the possible states? combinations of locked, woken and starving as you see from the const block.

Now depending on how long the goroutine has been waiting on the waitlist it will get priority on when to check again if the mutex is now free.

But also observe that only Unlock() can set the mutexLocked bit back to 0. 
in the Lock() CAS loop the only bits that are set are the starving and woken ones.Yes you can have multiple readers but only one writer at any time, and that writer is the one who is holding the mutex and is executing its protected path until calling Unlock(). Check out [this article](https://morganwu277.github.io/2018/06/19/from-mutex-to-distributed-lock/) for more details.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  The code "  old := m.state
 " on line 85 in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.12/src/sync/mutex.go confuse me , because m.state is direct read without atomic ensuration.

Comment: since the values are atomically read by compareAndSwaps what would be the point of an atomic Load() there? the documentation of the atomic package says that compareandswaps read atomically the value before they compare and possibly set (all those in one step).

Comment: yes i understand and i am claiming that it doesn't need to be. let's say it's not and look at the first time it's used. it is loaded unatomically and checked that it doesn't contain the woken and starving bits set. if they are not set and runtime_canSpin(iter) is true it enters that if statement. then if mutexwoken is not set it enters the second if and only then it matters. it matters because at that point it atomically makes sure that the m.state is still == old and only then it sets it to old|mutexWoken. so if that premise has changed in the meantime it doesn't matter.CAS won't set it.

Comment: Yeah, My point is that why race detector did not detect the race condition for read.

Comment: func Test(){
    a := int32(1)
        go func(){
                atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&a, 1, 4)
        }()
        _ = a
}  This function will cause a race condtion.

Comment: cause he is only reading the val not setting it. the example that matches this case would be this:func Test(val *int32) {
        a := *val;
        go func() {
                atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(val, 1, 4);
        }();
        _ = a;
}

func main() {
        sval := int32(4);
        Test(&sval);
}
this doesn't have a race as expected.

Comment: I mean if  put my Test function in the file sync/mute.go, It will not trick race warning.

Answer (score 0):

By disassemble the binary output file, The Test function in different pack generate different code.

The reason is that the compiler forbid to generate race detect instrument in the sync package.

The code is :

```
var norace_inst_pkgs = []string{"sync", "sync/atomic"}  // https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.12/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/racewalk.go
``
```